# How do functions maintain state in python?

Tags: python

I have this piece of code in python which I fail to understand as how are these functions maintain their state when encapsulated in class.

```
class Param(object):

def bad_append(self, item, l=[]):
    l.append(item)
    return l


p = Param()
print(p.bad_append(1))
print(p.bad_append(2))

pp = Param()
print(pp.bad_append(100))
```

**Output**

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 100]
```

I can't understand as why the output for pp is `[1, 2, 100]` instead of `[100]`.

Comment: I think Its appending again and again to same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is a gotcha of Python, the default parameter of the function is a globally shared value. Let me suggest the following change:

```
def bad_append(self, item, l=None):
  l = l or []
  #rest of code...
```

By setting the default to `None` and then reassigning to any list, you'll avoid the shared state.

Comment: Another gotcha is that the OP doesn't actually need to return l, or rather, if you return l, your original l value will still be changed because lists are mutable.